# Create multiple webpack bundles for different targets and have browser choose based on capabilities?

Tags: webpack, cross-browser, babel-polyfill

In order to support older browsers I need to import Babel's polyfill and the newer features, which result in very short code, need to be expanded into more verbose code -- resulting in bloated bundles.

I would like to have Webpack output multiple bundles:

- Newer browsers don't need the polyfill and can use things like Promises, Arrow Functions and `async` / `await`.  This means the code bundle can be smaller and load faster.
- Older browsers get the bundle that has more in it and loads slower.

Once I have those 2 bundles, how can I determine which bundle script to load?  I imagine I can do a check for `window.Promise` or something like that but not sure all the things I would need to check.

Comment: Have you considered using polyfill.io? It sniffs the browser and serves up a set of polyfills only if they are needed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that library.  Thanks.  It won't cover `async` / `await` but at least it will get the `Array` functions and `Promise`.

Comment: That's true, new syntax will require transpilation.

Comment: Have you measured the size of your bundles with and without transpilation? Generating multiple bundles is a lot of work, you should know what you stand to gain. It may not be worth it.